# Is this approach for const pointers okay?

Tags: c++

I want to provide different levels of const 'access' to my data. For example, depending on whether the pointer or data should be modified. So this is what I came up with:

```
class MyClass
{
    int n;
    int* ptr_to_data;
    int* const const_ptr_to_data;
    const int * ptr_to_const_data;
public:
    MyClass(int nn) 
        : n(nn),
          ptr_to_data(&n),
          const_ptr_to_data(ptr_to_data),
          ptr_to_const_data(ptr_to_data)
    {
    }
    ~MyClass() { }

    int& get_data()
    {
        return *const_ptr_to_data;
    }

    const int& get_data() const
    {
        return *ptr_to_const_data;
    }
};
```

The goal here is to avoid programmer errors by restricting as much access as possible. Is this a good approach, how to make it better?

Comment: You would typically just make a `const` getter like `int get_data() const {return n;}`

Comment: @Cyber Yes, for examples graphics.

Comment: You'd need to declare a copy-constructor and maybe a copy-assignment operator (and possibly their move counterparts) - this will do bad things if you copy an object. But these pointers serve no purpose, and don't add any protection to just returning `n` from the accessors.

Comment: @Mike What if I only need to load the expensive thing once? I don't want to copy it.

Comment: If you don't want the class to be copyable then you need to make it non-copyable. Currently it can be copied, and will do the wrong thing because of all those pointless pointers.

Comment: @user4320030: Then delete the copy constructor so you don't accidentally copy it with the implicit one and end up with pointers to the wrong place. Or define it correctly in case you decide you do want to copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointers you store don't help with the access problem, as you'll see, but they will refer to data in the wrong instance when you copy an object, unless you take charge of copying. And the top level `const` prevents assignment for class instances. I.e. the pointers are problematic, and do not contribute any advantage.

Instead do this:

```
int data() const
{
    return n_;
}

void set_data( int const value )
{
    n_ = value;
}
```

Or you might do as in the standard library and name also the setter just `data`, but the imperative form is more readable in the calling code.

---

A key feature of this approach is *not pass out a pointer or reference to non-`const`* data member.

Because by passing out unrestricted reference or pointer you lose all control over changes to that data member, in particular with respect to maintaining a class invariant, possibly other related values, imposing range restrictions, checking when changes are made, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

You have the correct approach with the two `get_data` functions, but all the pointers just make the code harder to maintain. Just this is sufficient:

```
int& get_data() { return n; }
const int& get_data() const { return n; }
```

Comment: The `get_` prefix indicates rather the wrong thing for the first function, which is more like a setter, and for the second it only provides an extra level of verbosity. I.e., ungood in both cases, but especially for the setter.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - you ain't kidding! I once wrote a library which had a `GetXxx()` function which actually provided a non-`const` reference, and as a consequence could be used as a setter: boy was that confusing when I went back to it a year later!